# How to copy a Python module and it's dependencies to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I want to use a Python module like `urllib.request` but have all the module's dependencies in a file where I can use them on a computer without having the entire Python installation.

Is there a module or tool I can use to just copy a specific module into a file and it's dependencies without having to go through the entire script and copying it manually.  I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a variety of options available to do this sort of thing. The one that comes to mind first off the top of my head is python's built-in zip support; if you have a `__main__.py` in your zip, running python on the zip file will run it as a script. Simple (pure-python, non-OS-dependent) packages should be simply embeddable into such a zip file.

Alternatively, tools such as [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) can package a script with its dependencies including the interpreter in an OS-specific fashion. This will typically result in a larger footprint as the resulting bundle includes the interpreter as well, but allows including more complex dependencies with native components; I'm not sure this is possible with python's zip import functionality.

Comment: I am not familiar with the first part.  If I put it into a zip will it run like a normal module?  Does `__main__.py` just needs to be what a normal module contains?  Do you know where I could find documentation for this?  Thanks for this possible solution (+1).

Comment: As an experiment I've created a virtualenv, installed requests in it, copied everything in `venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` into the root of the zip file, put a simple `__main__.py` (`import requests; print(requests.get("http://ix.io/M3M").text)`) into it, and tried running it in a python that doesn't have requests available. It worked :) I don't actually know that much about the functionality myself but it seems to work quite magically.

Comment: Not to worry about the docs I am not surprised but it's worth asking in case I missed it (I have a habit of missing the important parts).  Thanks for the example. : }

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipimport.html) what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, looks like it.

Comment: Good, I think that's my question sorted then. : )

Answer (score 1):

Use a container tech.
Docker, for example, gives you the ability to port your code with dependencies to any machine you want without you have to install anything new in the machine and it saves a lot of time too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have decided the other answer is more useful in this case.