# How to create setup offline of python script

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, offline, setup.py

I have python script that I build in python 2.7, this script use with some library that I install with pip.

I want to create a setup to this script that I can share with another people .

This setup need to be offline(without internet connection) and need to install all the dependencies.

How can I pack my script(in Windows) and all the dependencies (library) so another one can run `python setup.py` and get install all the library that the script need.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383369/how-to-copy-a-python-module-and-its-dependencies-to-a-file], but appears to be answered there. Check out [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.org/project/cx_Freeze/)

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation) may help you.

Comment: You might want to check out [Pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: @HarryCutts pyinstaller create a exe file from python script , I want running the python script after setup